# I would like to have met her

Tags: ambiguity, syntactic-analysis, present-perfect, semantics

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, page 148, reads

> ***I would like to have met her*** and ***I would have liked to have met her***, which are often used to convey the same meaning as *I would have liked to
>   meet her*,  are ambiguous: they also have interpretations in which
>   anteriority applies to the meeting. These interpretations are
>   pragmatically unlikely in the examples chosen, but become more salient
>   if we change *met her* to *ﬁnished it*.

What are the two interpretations of such sentences which make them ambiguous?

Comment: In *I would have liked to meet her*, it is clear that you haven't ever met. But in the two bolded sentences, it is somewhat ambiguous as to whether you ever met at a later time.

Comment: ***I would like to have met her*** explicitly indicates that *right now, at time of speaking*, I ***still*** regret the fact of not meeting her, whereas (in principle, at least) ***I would have liked to have met her*** implies that my regret is now ***in the past***. But in practice, most native speakers / listeners wouldn't normally neither intend / understand that fine point, which wouldn't be likely to have much if any real-world significance.

Comment: The ambiguity arises because it is possible to apply the past (anterior) meaning to either the liking or the meeting.

Comment: (As Cambridge point out, if the thing that never happened was ***finished it*** as opposed to ***met her***, the different tense choices might have more significant real-world implications.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers then to which meaning does _anteriority applies to the meeting_ apply?

Comment: ***I would like to have finished it before I go*** expresses my *current desire* to be in a specified state (that of having finished something) at some specified time *in the future* (when I leave). Note that ***I would have liked to have finished it before I go*** is a very unlikely permutation (for most contexts it would be ***...before I went***). But for both of those, ***would have liked*** implies it's no longer my current desire, because that's ***no longer even a possibility*** (regardless of whether I've already left by time of utterance).

Comment: @FumbleFingers But can't _''I would have liked to meet her''_ be said even when you still want to meet her (even if it's no longer possible, for example because of her demise)?

Comment: Well, you can argue 'til the cows come home about whether *I would **have liked** to **meet** her* means something slightly different to *I would **have liked** to **have met** her* or *I would like to **have met** her*. Not to mention several more permutations if the speaker places heavy stress on ***would*** or ***like/liked***, any or all of which might convey subtly different nuances. But you'll never get unanimous agreement on what exactly those differences are, or whether they even actually exist at all. And as they say, it might change with ***finish[ed] it*** rather than ***met her***.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between these two, is ***when*** the desire (to meet) is occurring.

1. In: **'I would like to have met her'** the desire is occurring *now*, in the present moment. 'I... **like**'. Present.
2. In **'I would have liked to have met her'** the desire is occurring in the past. I... **liked**. Past tense.

So in the first, the desire is being felt **now, looking back.**

In the second, the speaker is projecting themselves back into the past, and feeling the desire (or projected, or imagined desire) **back then.**

Neither necessarily means that any meeting actually took place; they are expressions of feeling, felt now, or projecting back to the past.

The same is true if you substitute 'finished it' - it's the 'like' and 'liked' that tell us what is going on, here.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/would-have

Answer (score -4):

The following are the two different meanings that are alluded to:

> 1. I would have liked to have met her.

I wish we could have met.

> 2. I would have liked to have met her.

I'm sure I would have enjoyed the experience of meeting her.

---

The ambiguity comes from the use of *like*. It can be used in its literal sense of pleasure, happiness, or accord, or it can be used to convey a sense of wishing for something.

For instance:

> I would like you to get on with the terribly painful torture now.

The use of *like* here is an indication, phrased politely, of your desire for some action. In this case, it most definitely will not be a pleasant experience; you won't *actually* like it. It's simply being used as part of a request.

> I would like the taste of a world-class meal.

Here, *like* is (probably) talking about how the thing will be pleasant. But it could also be talking about the desire to experience it—whether you'd actually enjoy it or not. No pun intended, but it's likely you'd enjoy it.

Comment: Interesting contrast between two identical sentences.